# Sumar las filas por nombres pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un marco de datos como este, pero mas grande y con mas zonas. Estoy tratando de sumar el valor de las filas por sus nombres. Este es mi codigo pero me da error. El total de las sumas de las zonas R o C van en la columna `total` y el total de las sumas de las zonas M va en la columna `total1`.

> "C1" no aparece en la lista.

Esto pasa porque el programa esta tratando de sumar el valor de C1 cuando encuentra cualquier otro valor que hace que la condicion del `If` statement sea verdad.

Marco:

```
ID  Zone1   CHC1    Valor1  Zone2     CHC2  Valor2  Zone3   CHC3    Valor3  total   total1
1   R5B     100      10       C2        0     20      R10A   2       5        35       0
1   C2       95      20      M2-6       5      6      R5B    7       3        23       6       
3   C2       40      4        C4       60      6       0     6       0        10       0
3   C1       100     8         0        0      0       0    100      0        8        0
5   M1-5     10      6       M2-6      86     15       0     0       0        0        21
```

Codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:PATH")

total = []
total1 = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    temp = df.iloc[i].tolist()
    if ("R5B" in temp) |("R10A" in temp) | ("C2" in temp) | ("C1" in temp) | ("C4" in temp) :
        total.append(temp[temp.index("R5B")+2] + temp[temp.index("R10A")+2] +temp[temp.index("C2")+2] + temp[temp.index("C1")+2] +temp[temp.index("C4")+2])
    if ("M1-5" in temp) | ("M2-6" in temp):
        total1.append(temp[temp.index("M1-5")+2] + temp[temp.index("M2-6")+2])

df["Total"] = total
df["Total1"] = total1

print (df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto logra lo que quieres, y funciona con cualquiera cantidad de `Zone1`, `Zone2`, ..., `ZoneN`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"ID":     [1,1,3,3,5],
     "Zone1":  ["R5B","C2","C2","C1","M1-5"],
     "Valor1": [10,20,4,8,6],
     "Zone2":  ["C2","M2-6","C4","0","M2-6"],
     "Valor2": [20,6,6,0,15],
     "Zone3":  ["R10A","R5B","0","0","0"],
     "Valor3": [5,3,0,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

headers = list(df)
headers.sort()
valors = [h for h in headers if h.startswith("Valor")]
zones  = [h for h in headers if h.startswith("Zone")]

rc = ["R","C"]
m  = ["M"]

# Si ZonaX empieza por 'R' o 'C', sumará ValorX
df["total"] = sum(df[zone].str[0].isin(rc) * df[valor] 
                  for zone, valor in zip(zones, valors))

# Si ZonaX empieza por 'M', sumará ValorX
df["total1"] = sum(df[zone].str[0].isin(m) * df[valor] 
                  for zone, valor in zip(zones, valors))
```

```
print(df)

   ID Zone1  Valor1 Zone2  Valor2 Zone3  Valor3  total  total1
0   1   R5B      10    C2      20  R10A       5     35       0
1   1    C2      20  M2-6       6   R5B       3     23       6
2   3    C2       4    C4       6     0       0     10       0
3   3    C1       8     0       0     0       0      8       0
4   5  M1-5       6  M2-6      15     0       0      0      21
```

Comment: Gracias esto resolvio mi problema.